# Read framebuffer in metal shader

Tags: ios, swift, metal

Render an image in two steps. 
It needs two pair vertex and fragment shader.

In the second step, the second fragment shader needs the frame buffer rendered by first pair shader.

How to get the frame buffer or the color in a special coordinate.

I have read the following answer.

[iOS Metal Shader - Texture read and write access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131953/ios-metal-shader-texture-read-and-write-access/36212082#36212082)

[How to chain filters in Metal for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162007/how-to-chain-filters-in-metal-for-ios/40164898#40164898)

```
fragment float4 second_fragment(VertexOut vert [[stage_in]],
                               texture2d<float> tex [[texture(0)]],
                                float4 framebuffer [[color(0)]]
                               ) {
    float4 textureColor = tex.sample(basicSampler,vert.texCoor);
    return textureColor;
}
```

`[[color(0)]]` qualifier only get the color in current coordinate. I need to know the color in any other coordinate.

Comment: @warrenm please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773658/metal-off-screen-drawing-with-multi-sampling  I guess I get the right answer :)

Comment: If you need to read or sample from arbitrary coordinates of the color attachment of your first pass, you'll need to render to an intermediate color render target, then bind it as a parameter in your second pass. Framebuffer fetch (using the `[[color(n)]]` syntax) only allows you to get the existing color value at the pixel associated with the current fragment.